# Getting node id inside block template with Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Alright, so I've created a template file for one of my blocks, which works just fine. However inside this template I would like to get the id of the current node. How is that possible? I've tried arg, $node and all of these variables, but none of them are available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I love you for asking this question! ;)

Answer (score 23):

Assuming you're on the node page itself the [`menu_get_object()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) function will return the node object:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if ($node && $node->nid) {
  // You have a valid node to work with.
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not a safe assumption.

Comment: @Jeff For the phrase "current node" it's a safe assumption (that's what that phrase refers to in Drupal-eze). If it's a not a node page what "current node" are you looking for? There's likely to be a similarly easy method to find it

Comment: On second read, yes, I suppose you are right. I read 'current node' as the node for the current block.

Answer (score 0):

```
// it will gives only node id.
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
    $nid = arg(1);
}
echo $nid;
```